# How to embed big size graph in 2 columns format

Tags: graphs

I use the [amcs template](https://www.amcs.uz.zgora.pl/downloads/Instructions_AMCS.pdf)

This is the graph I need to add to the paper:
[image]

However, its size is too big to fit into one column format.
This is my code:

```
\documentclass{amcs}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics [scale=0.20]{Figure9Graph5.png}
    \caption{Algorithms Running time over testing dataset}
    \label{fig:Test5}
    \end{figure}

     \end{document}
```

What can I do in order that its content be seen and still match the template format?

Comment: Use `figure*` instead of `figure` (mind the asterisk.

Comment: Never use `[H]` to begin with. Next, do `\begin{figure*}<contents>\end{figure*}`. You also want to use `width=\textwidth` instead of `scale=0.2`.

Comment: By the way, using `[H]`  makes it clear that something dodgy is going on.

Comment: Please, fix the link that points nowhere.

Comment: Thanks to all! Now I get the graph that is crossing the both paper columns is it eligible? In addition, its location is at the head of page and it comes before a graph that has to appear before him.

Comment: Try to redraw graph with for example `pgfplots` and make it narrower. From provided image it seems feasibility. Doing this on the graph will become more easy to read all text on it (now is almost invisible ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `amcs` class supports `figure*`:

```
\documentclass{amcs}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author[ad1][]{First name LAST NAME}

\correspondingauthor{Fifth AUTHOR}

\address[ad1]{Institute of xxx xxx xxx xxx\\ University of xxx xxx, 
  Address xxx xxx xx xxx xxx\\ e-mail: \url{xxx xx xxx}}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure*}

\includegraphics[
  width=\textwidth,
  height=4cm, % for emulating your picture
]{example-image}

\caption{Algorithms Running time over testing dataset}
\label{fig:Test5}

\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

[image]