# How to make table span over two columns in one column template

Tags: tables, columns

I use the following [template](https://www.amcs.uz.zgora.pl/?action=guide).
The template format uses two-column style:
[image]
I would like to add 2 table that will use the both columns of the page, like this:
[image]
I would like to add it to the last pages of the paper.
What do I have to change in the table definitions?
Here is what I use:

```
\documentclass{amcs}
\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
    {\\Appendix: Accasddy of SSSS accuracy vs. efdsf mFDsfd vooo (3 digit format)} \label{appendix:AppendixA}   
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ c S[table-format=2.0] 
                S[table-format=1.3] 
                S[table-format=1.4] c c c }
            \toprule
            \thead{Dataset}  
            &   {\thead{Number\\ of Sfghes}} 
            &   {\thead{Efffffff 748\\ Accuracy}}
            &   {\thead{Syyy 448\\ Accuracy}}
            &  \thead{Difference}
            &   \thead{P-value}
            &   \thead{Tssssss  \\ Ssss }                 \\ 
            \midrule
            Ppppp & 32  & 0.632 & 0.592 & -0.04  &  \textless0.001 & 100000  \\ 
            Ppppp & 64  & 0.594 & 0.566 & -0.028 &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\ 
            Ppppp & 128 & 0.537 & 0.533 & -0.003 &  0.051 & 100000 \\
            \addlinespace
            Ppppp & 256  & 0.499 & 0.521 & 0.022  &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\
            Ppppp & 512  & 0.499 & 0.525 & 0.026  &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\
            Ppppp & 1024 & 0.499 & 0.484 & -0.014 &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\
            \addlinespace
            SSSS & 32   & 0.543 & 0.788 & 0.245   &  \textless0.001& 500000   \\
            SSSS & 64   & 0.543 & 0.786 & 0.242   &  \textless0.001& 500000   \\
            SSSS & 128  & 0.543 & 0.783 & 0.239   &  \textless0.001& 500000   \\
            \addlinespace
            SSSS &  256 & 0.543 & 0.778 & 0.234  &  \textless0.001 & 500000 \\
            SSSS &  512 & 0.543 & 0.772 & 0.228  &  \textless0.001 & 500000 \\
            SSSS &  1024& 0.781 & 0.767 & -0.013 &  \textless0.001 & 500000 \\
            \addlinespace
            RRRR &  32  & 0.781 & 0.767 & -2E-05 &  0.281    & 100000 \\
            RRRR &  64  & 0.999 & 0.999 & -5E-05 &  0.137    & 100000 \\
            RRRR &  128 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -6E-05 &  0.144    & 100000 \\
            \addlinespace
            RRRR &  256 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -4E-05  &  0.327 & 50000  \\
            RRRR &  512 & 1     & 1     &    0    &  -     & 10000  \\
            RRRR &  1024& 1     & 0.999 & -0.0002 &  0.078 & 10000  \\
            \addlinespace
            KKK CCC &   32  & 0.998 & 0.993 & -0.005  &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
            KKK CCC &   64  & 0.997 & 0.997 & -0.0007 &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
            KKK CCC &   128 & 0.996 & 0.995 & -0.001  &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
            \addlinespace
            KKK CCC &   256 & 0.995 & 0.993 & -0.002 &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
            KKK CCC &   512 & 0.988 & 0.987 & -0.001 &  0.036   & 50000  \\
            KKK CCC &   1024& 0.984 & 0.984 & 1E-04  &  0.477   & 10000  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}

        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ c S[table-format=2.0] 
                S[table-format=1.3] 
                S[table-format=1.4] c c c}
            \toprule
            \thead{Dataset}  
            &   {\thead{Number\\ of Ssssss}} 
            &   {\thead{Eeeeeeee CCCC\\ Aaaaaaaa}}
            &   {\thead{Ssss CCCC\\ Aaaaaaaa}}
            &  \thead{Difference}
            &   \thead{P-value}
            &   \thead{Ttttttt  \\ Ssss }                  \\ 
            \midrule
            Ppppp & 32  & 0.563 & 0.549 & -0.014 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\ 
            Ppppp & 64  & 0.550 & 0.542 & -0.007 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\ 
            Ppppp & 128 & 0.536 & 0.533 & -0.003 & 0.096    & 100000 \\
            \addlinespace
            Ppppp & 256  & 0.521 & 0.504 & -0.016 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\
            Ppppp & 512  & 0.499 & 0.486 & -0.013 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\
            Ppppp & 1024 & 0.499 & 0.471 & -0.027 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\
            \addlinespace
            SSSS & 32   & 0.791 & 0.784 & -0.006 &\textless0.001& 500000   \\
            SSSS & 64   & 0.787 & 0.779 & -0.008 &\textless0.001& 500000   \\
            SSSS & 128  & 0.781 & 0.769 & -0.012 &\textless0.001& 500000   \\
            \addlinespace
            SSSS &  256 & 0.781 & 0.765 & -0.016 &\textless0.001& 500000 \\
            SSSS &  512 & 0.781 & 0.756 & -0.025 &\textless0.001& 500000 \\
            SSSS &  1024& 0.781 & 0.751 & -0.03  &\textless0.001& 500000 \\
            \addlinespace
            RRRR &  32  & 0.999 & 0.999 & -1E-05 & 0.44  & 100000 \\
            RRRR &  64  & 0.999 & 0.999 & -1E-05 & 0.44  & 100000 \\
            RRRR &  128 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -5E-05 & 0.222 & 100000 \\
            \addlinespace
            RRRR &  256 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -0.0007 &\textless0.001& 50000  \\
            RRRR &  512 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -1E-04  & 0.352    & 10000  \\
            RRRR &  1024& 0.999 & 0.999 & 0.0003  & 0.182    & 10000  \\
            \addlinespace
            KKK CCC &   32  & 0.992 & 0.990 & -0.002 &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
            KKK CCC &   64  & 0.987 & 0.987 & 0      & 0.5      & 150000 \\
            KKK CCC &   128 & 0.987 & 0.987 & -8E-05 & 0.455    & 150000 \\
            \addlinespace
            KKK CCC &   256 & 0.987 & 0.987 & 2E-05  & 0.488 & 150000 \\
            KKK CCC &   512 & 0.984 & 0.984 & 0.0003 & 0.431 & 50000  \\
            KKK CCC &   1024& 0.984 & 0.998 & 0.0139 &\textless0.001& 10000  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table} 
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the `table*` environment.

Comment: Thanks, can you please elaborate, how can I do it?

Comment: Very simple: write `begin{table*} … \end{table*}` instead of  `begin{table} … \end{table}`.

Comment: I tried this and I get no results for the table (the tables disappear). By the way, after the tables I have reference list that has 2 columns format. In addition, when the results disappeared, I saw the headlines in 2 column format and I need to change it as well.

Comment: how the two-column format is set up is a function of the document class.  according to this question [How to embed big size graph in 2 columns format](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/336825/579) the `amcs` class does use the `twocolumn` mechanism, so `table*` ought to work.

Comment: Thanks Barbara. I think the problem is due to the reference list that comes after. If I omit the reference it displays the tables in one page without the need to use table*. Whereas the appendix headline is displayed in the previous page weirdly. I use the following lines for reference: 
\newpage
\bibliography{BibliographyFinal2}
\bibliographystyle{harvard}

Comment: If it is only one page, one can leave two column mode using \onecolumn (followed by \twocolumn).

Comment: Thanks John, can you please elaborate how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If the template uses the `multicol` package, you can simply break the `multicol` environment before the table and start it again after the table.

```
\begin{multicol}
text
\end{multicol}
-table-
\begin{multicol}
text
\end{multicol}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I use the template \documentclass{amcs} as described in the code above. There is no explicit usage of multicol.